# Exception handling when using tail -f to monitor a log

Tags: shell-script, logs, tail, error-handling

I have a main script calling the script to do the monitoring.

I am trying to catch the exception that the log is missing or not accessible anymore.

`tail -f` is used instead of `-F` since the logs are named with the current date.

`trap` may be working but I am not sure what signal `tail -f` would return if the log being monitored is no longer there.

Otherwise, should I just do a loop checking in the main script checking for `[ -r $Log]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just gave it a try and see what the main problem is here.

If I do a `tail -f` on an existing file and then remove the file, `tail` will not notice that at all. The reson is simple: `tail -f` opens a read-only-file-handle that references the content of the file. Now if the file vanishes, only the meta-directory-entry vanishes. The allocation will be freed, when the last FH closes - which is `tail` in this case.

So you have to

- put `tail -f` into a background-process of its own, remember its PID.
- Start another process that monitors the existence of the file (in a while-loop every second or something like that)
- If that monitor sees that the file has gone, it has to signal the PID of the corresponding tail-process - with a signal of your choice - you can use `trap` within the tail-process.

Answer (score 2):

The `tail` program won't notice that the file has been deleted. You need something else for that. The [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) facility on Linux allows an application to be notified on file events; most other unices have similar facilities. The following command prints a notification when `file.log` is deleted:

```
inotifywait -e delete file.log
```

Comment: `tail -F` does notice that the file has been deleted (or created), but I didn't see a way of using it in a script. There is also `--max-unchanged-stats`, but the man page says: "With inotify, this option is rarely useful".

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tail -f blah
tail: cannot open `blah' for reading: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
1
```

You could test for that when the file does not exist in the first place, but it won't help you if the file becomes inaccessible. A `while` loop may be better in this scenario:

```
while [ 1 ]
do
        tail $1
        if [ "$?" != "0" ]
        then
                echo "No access to file"
                exit 1
        fi
done
```

I got the idea in a [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2041579/1081569). There are alternatives there, but this one is simple.

Comment: Won't the `while` loop keeps creating new `tail` processes?

Comment: Yes. That's not necessarily a problem, but I think Gilles' solution is the most elegant.